# Image as a link using wp_nav_menu()

Tags: menus, images, links

In creating a custom navigation menu in TwentyTen ( WP3.01), is it possible to make an image a link to a page on the same site, using wp_nav_menu() ? Is it the case that wp_nav_menu() echos or returns only text and cannot be made to return or echo an image? If this is the case, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS to add an image instead of text

see:

- http://wpweaver.info/menu-bar-and-background-images/
- http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/cutline-gt-coraline-replacing-menu-items-with-graphics
- http://wpveda.com/how-to-add-images-inside-wordpress-3-0-custom-menu/